# Do the Vedas allow Shudras to do undergo Upanayanam or perform Yajnas?

Tags: vedas, caste-system, varna, shudra

Can Shudras do Upanayanam or perform Yajnas as per Vedas?

Comment: I believe Vedas do not accept varnas to be based on birth and Varna migration is possible too. It doesn't matter if Sudra perform Yajna or Upanayana (unless doesn't follow process)

Comment: @CR241 Vedas support birth based caste system. All the castes were created from the body of the Purusha.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the *Taittiriya* Samhita of the Krishna Yajur Veda forbids Shudras from engaging in sacrifices.

7.1.1 [says](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/yv/yv07.htm):

> From his feet he meted out the Ekavinça Stoma. After it the Anustubh
>   metre [5] was created, the Vairaja Saman, of men the Çudra [Shudra], of cattle
>   the horse. Therefore the two, the horse and the Çudra, are dependent
>   on others. **Therefore the Çudra is not fit for the sacrifice, for he
>   was not created after any gods.** Therefore they depend on their feet,
>   **for they were created from the feet.**

Also, note the phrase "for they were created from the feet", is found in the Purusha Sukta hymn as well.

Comment: birth & guna/karma are like 2 sides of the same coin. your guna/karma/occupation in this birth determines your varna in next birth. and varna determines what guna/karma/occupation you are supposed to cultivate. if i am born in a brahmana kula, but take up agriculture/business, then in next birth, i am born as vaishya (after some punishment for not following brahmana-karma). then in that birth, instead of doing job of vaishya, if I take up arms to fight, then the next birth after that, i am born as kshatriya (after some punishment for not following vaishya-karma).

Comment: whatever kula i am born in is the best-suited for my tastes according to innumerable past vasanas. there was no confusion about this in ancient days. but due to varna-sankara (caste-mixing), which was feared by Arjuna in Gita, people are now confused because they have both characteristics from parents - if father brahmana & mother vaishya, child may have tendencies to be a business consultant. father kshatriya & wife shudra, child wanna be an army peon. that's why people nowadays are questioning the very foundation of varna-ashrama dharma, cos there is more confusion than clarity.

Comment: they want to cut off the head to cure headache. there is no inherent fault in 'birth-based' system. but since people can't/don't follow it, they question the ideal.

Comment: Satya kama jabala is famous rishi.. in moksha dharma bhisma defines the qualities of bhramana(daya, constant thinking of god, satya, souchaman ..etc.) if the same qualities are found he should be regarded as brahmana..but for yagnas one should intiation its vicious cycle.

Comment: @prasannaragothaman Satya Kama Jabala was born as a Brahmin, the Brahma Sutra commentators unanimously agree on this.

Comment: @Ikshvaku Again I had to tell you that there are interpolation in story to suit Bharmin priest ego please follow bannaje govindacharaya moksha darhma lecture in YouTube 8,9 and 10

Comment: @prasannaragothaman It is quite unlikely that the Taittiriya Samhita of the Yajur Veda and Brahma Sutras are interpolated....

Comment: It is not an interpolation. @prasannaragothaman

Comment: I'm not saying that above scripture it s interpolation but  story regarding Satya kama that he was born Bharmin is interpolation

Comment: @prasannaragothaman The fact that Satya Kama was born a Brahman is said by Gautama Rishi himself in the Chhandogya Upanishad.

Comment: its duplicate question .. and false translation i think

Comment: This is only for certain Yajnas (which are mentioned in that chapter) not for all Yajnas. Also, just because for (few) Yajnas they are not allowed, it is not correct to say Vedas prohibit them from performing Yajna or study. But Smritis and other scriptures say they don't have any samskara to purify.