# Is the practice of Gayatri Parivar allowing everyone to undergo Upanayana (Janaeu) ceremony adharmika?

Tags: practice, dharma-shastras, sin, varna, yagnopavitam

It's a well-known fact about the [Gayatri Parivar's](http://www.awgp.org/spiritual_wisdom/sacramental_rites/yagyopaveet_sanskar) [stance](http://www.awgp.org/social_initiative/social_projects/women_empowerment) on allowing everyone (including married women, non-Hindus, and Śhūdras, etc.) to undergo the sacred thread ceremony (Upanayana or Yagnopavita saṃskāra), thus allowing everyone in the society to become a *dwija*.

However, as per major/authoritative Smṛtis, Puraṇas and Dharma śhāstras - [only the top three varṇa are authorized](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2892/is-janeva-yaj%C3%B1opav%C4%ABtam-or-sacred-thread-limited-to-brahmins-only) to be "dwija". Further, [for women](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6667/rules-for-wearing-yagyopavit-by-women-yes-it-is-possible), only *Brahmavadinis* may be initiated and not the married (*Sadyovadhu*). However, they initiate married women too. Further, [Śhūdras are forbidden too.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31635/do-the-vedas-allow-shudras-to-do-undergo-upanayanam-or-perform-yajnas)

However, here we have the Gayatri Parivar, giving the "dwija-initiation" to all members of the society.

Furthermore, from their ["guidebooks"](http://literature.awgp.org/book/Gayatri_Aur_Yagyopavit/v1.25) - it seems that they follow the "karma and guṇa based varṇāhśrama vyavasthā". However, as per [several QnA discussions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16893/why-casteism-var%E1%B9%87a-system-is-based-on-birth-instead-of-present-gu%E1%B9%87a-s-karma), [on this site](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/43820/which-is-right-varna-based-on-birth-or-varna-based-on-guna-and-karma), [majority view](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26839/according-to-gun%CC%A3a-based-varn%CC%A3a-system-can-a-christian-or-muslim-be-also-a-br%C4%81h) **might** be tending to support the [Birth-based varṇāhśrama system](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31859/do-sruti-texts-mention-either-or-both-of-birth-based-varna-and-guna-based-varna).

---

**Question -**

**If purely looked at from scriptural perspectives,** 
 isn't this a violation of the scriptures and thus a grave sin?
 Is the practice by Gayatri Parivar of initiating everyone with Janaeu an *adharmika* act?
 Or, since they follow the "karma and guṇa based varṇāhśrama vyavasthā" they are exempted from the *adharmika* tags and thus, no sins committed? 
  If it's sinful, then what scriptural repercussions will they face after death?
Please give a proper scripturally sourced answer.

---

**NOTE:** IMO, this is not an Opinion-based question because I'm asking if their acts or practices are in line or out of line, with the "major" Vedic and Dharmika śhāstras injunctions.

Comment: Not sure but may be they believe in karma based varna instead of birth based..

Comment: The book on their website "Gayatri and Yagnopavitam" mentions few things, "a possible reason" why they are extending it to everyone: http://literature.awgp.org/book/Gayatri_Aur_Yagyopavit/v1.25 also see page 1, 8, 9, and 12. (Its in hindi, idk how many can read it)

Comment: @Proxy , basically their stance is based on the *Karma-based* varnashrama system only. However, I doubt, if "major" scriptural guidelines give support to that kind of system. Most favour birth as the most necessary condition (however, not the only condition), but Birth-varna is necceasrily enjoined as essential , by all major scriptures.

Comment: @Proxy pls write that as answer ..

Comment: Your question is asking for opinions, since the answer will vary from sect to sect. Any shastra will be puranic or tantric and will depend upon a specific sect's view.

Comment: Mr. Vishwananda then every question should be closed as opinion based as each questions have different answers based on different sect. We cannot ask questions at all.

Comment: @YDS I will think about it....